# How to add values to input fields in form array

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my form, I have three fields which can be added and removed dynamically. I have done this part. It works fine.
But I want to add values to that fields from database.but it shows the error

```
  this.CreateEAuctionForm.get('upins').patchValue({
        mediaTyp: res[0].mtype,
        land:res[0].land
      });
```

I have tried the above code but it gives an error

> ERROR TypeError: value.forEach is not a function at
>   FormArray.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormArray.patchValue

Comment: is `upins` a form array? Then you are trying to set an object as the value for the formarray. Angular would of course complain that the types do not match.

Comment: yes upins is a form array. In that form array i have three input fields. From which i want to add value to two fields on change of other field.What should i do??

Comment: if you are certain that you **always have an formgroup** in the formarray, then you should use `patchValue` on the **formgroup** which is in the formarray.

Comment: Soory i did'nt get you...Can you explain me or can you show one example.It will help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are now trying to set an object (formgroup) as the value for the formarray. Angular would complain about that. If you are certain that there is always an formgroup in your formarray, you should patch the value on that formgroup. Which would be at the index `0`, just like "normal" arrays. But for insurance, let's check if there is a formgroup present, if so, patch the values, else push a new formgroup in the formarray:

```ts
 const formArr = <FormArray>this.CreateEAuctionForm.get('upins');

 // check that there is a formgroup inside the formarray at index 0
 if (formArr.at(0)) {
   formArr.at(0).patchValue({
     mediaTyp: res[0].mtype,
     land:res[0].land
   });
 } else {
   formArr.push(this.fb.group({
     mediaTyp: res[0].mtype,
     land:res[0].land
   }))
 }
```

... where `fb` refers to `FormBuilder`.

DEMO: [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhbkdf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Its gives error 
Argument of type '{ mediaTyp: any; land: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'mediaTyp' does not exist in type 'any[]'.

Comment: that error should not be thrown if your form is properly set up. I'll add a demo.

Comment: ok please show me demo it will be great help from you. I have stuck on this task

Comment: I added a demo at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I have seen your demo  
I have declare same as you declare.
`addUpin(): FormGroup {
   return this.fb.group({
      upin:['',Validators.required],
      mediaTyp:['',Validators.required],
      land:['',Validators.required]
    });
  }`

this is the function

Comment: This Is my res json
**0: {id: 2, media_type: 4, land: "Rakhiyal Circle", upin: "AMCADVT1415C0123", mtype: "KIOSK PACKAGE"}**

From this i want to add mtype and land to resp input fileds

Comment: well first of all your data has `media_type`, not `mtype`, so that needs to change. If my demo doesn't help, please fork it with as a working sample of **your** code.

Comment: I want to add value which is present in mtype, so i am using that.

Comment: aaah... sorry, overlooked a bit, didn't see that property ;) But anyway, fork the demo with your reproduced error and I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: Hey it works.Do you have make changes your demo code???
But i is fine with one array field..
I am adding multiple input fields for mtype and land
So what should I do??

Comment: I think we should pass array index in place of 0
`if (formArr.at(0)) {
  console.log('has formgroup');
  formArr.at(0).patchValue({
    mediaTyp: res[0].mtype,
    land: res[0].land
  });
} else {
  console.log('does not have a formgroup');
  formArr.push(this.fb.group({
    mediaTyp: res[0].mtype,
    land: res[0].land
  }))
}`

at(0) we should pass index of array

Comment: well that is not mentioned in your question at all... and no, I made no changes to the demo. if you have several values. loop them and push them to the array.

Comment: I have loop that fields in HTML.
How to Push using loop to array. Can You help me little bit more

Comment: I ask you once more, since I already solved your original issue. If you want further help, **please** fork my stackblitz with your issue. No-one is here to code **for you**. You need to make an effort yourself, especially since this has nothing to do with your original question!

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by **@AJT_82** is correct. But I have several values so I have find out solution in which I have just pass index of formarray.

```
    const formArr = <FormArray>this.CreateEAuctionForm.get('upins');

 // check that there is a formgroup inside the formarray at index 0
 if (formArr.at(id)) {
   formArr.at(id).patchValue({
     mediaTyp: res[0].mtype,
     land:res[0].land
   });
 } else {
   formArr.push(this.fb.group({
     mediaTyp: res[0].mtype,
     land:res[0].land
   }))
 }
```

Here **id** is the index of formarray which is created dynamic. Thank you **AJT_82P** for your solution, it helped me a lot.